# Unable to send mail using laravel smtp in Plesk Server

Tags: laravel, smtp

I am unable to configure email in `Plesk` Server.
I tried with `sendmail` driver but email still not working
i tried with different port with `smtp` but still not working
please help me to solve this issue

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.placenow.fr
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@placenow.fr
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Back to your host provider to check `SMTP` settings or try manual add email to outlook or mailbird

Comment: @MahmoudGamal please explain your answer i am not getting your point

Comment: Ask Your host support to provide you smtp settings   for your email
Try to add this email to outlook manual to check smtp settings